# Prisma how to look into the database

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql, prisma

I have followed https://www.prisma.io/docs/get-started/01-setting-up-prisma-new-database-JAVASCRIPT-a002 and gotten it to work. I can see the following:

- `docker ps` tells me that two docker containers are being run
- running `node index.js` each time shows a list of all users that have been created. hence, there is a database somewhere
- When I try `docker exec -it POSTGRE_CONTAINER_ID bash`, I get a command prompt.
- on the command prompt, when I type `psql` or `psql prisma`, i get `psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`

How do I see in which database/table is prisma saving my data in, and how do I connect to it?

Comment: what is your os?

Answer (score 4):

Prisma doesn't store data in the public schema by default. It stores it in an schema derived from your service name (`default$default` is the default when no service and stage is provided in the endpoint).

You can do the follow steps to see the underlying data:

1. Grab the docker container id using `docker ps`
2. Run `docker exec -it <POSTGRES_CONTAINER_ID> psql -U prisma`
3. List all the schemas using `\dn` to grab all schemas, and find the schema that your service is using(it is `default$default` by default)
4. Now run `SET search_path to <YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME_FROM_STEP_3>;` to change the default search path
5. Run `\dt` to list all tables. You can also run any SQL command now on that schema.

Comment: many thanks for the answer. the example given at https://www.prisma.io/docs/get-started/01-setting-up-prisma-new-database-JAVASCRIPT-a002 doesnt have any service. Hence, when I run \dn, I get three schemas - default$default, management, public . I tried doing step4 on all three of them, but \dt simply says `Did not find any relations` . Please help

Comment: try \dt default$default.

Also, a GUI like tableplus will make this task quite easy

Comment: prisma saves data in the public schema by default

Comment: @Amarsh did you try `\dt default$default.*`?

Answer (score 0):

I am using odcker to open MySQL:
`docker exec -it server_mysql_1 mysql -u root --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3306 --password=prisma`

Of course, use your own settings!

Answer (score 0):

you can type:
**psql postgresql://user:password@host:5432/postgresdb**

user = username you have used in dockerfile

password = password you have used

host = your host URL
postgresdb = your postgres db name from dockerfile