# How do I find the rows I put into my postgres db with Prisma in the psql command line?

Tags: postgresql, next.js, schema, psql, prisma

I created a schema with prisma. Here is what my prisma file looks like:
schema.prisma

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id            String       @default(cuid()) @id
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_at")
  is_confirmed  Boolean   @default(false)
  confirm_key   String
  @@map(name: "users")
}
```

I have a running instance of Postgres in a docker container and I referenced it like this in my env file:
.env

```
# See the documentation for more detail: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema#accessing-environment-variables-from-the-schema

# Prisma supports the native connection string format for PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, SQL Server, MongoDB and CockroachDB.
# See the documentation for all the connection string options: https://pris.ly/d/connection-strings

DATABASE_URL="postgresql://POSTGRES_USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:5432/DB_NAME?schema=users"
```

I ran the command `npx prisma db push` and it appeared to work because I got this in my terminal:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "DB_NAME", schema "users" at "localhost:5432"

  Your database is now in sync with your Prisma schema. Done in 132ms

Running generate... (Use --skip-generate to skip the generators)

added 2 packages, and audited 338 packages in 5s

117 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

✔ Generated Prisma Client (4.13.0 | library) to ./node_modules/@prisma/client in 51ms
```

I opened prisma studio with `npx prisma studio`

I added 2 entries via prisma studio:
[image]

But when I log into the db with psql, I can't find the data that I input into the db:

```
MYUSERNAME@MYCOMPUTERNAME my-current-directory % docker exec -it DOCKERCONTAINERNAME bash
root@DOCKERCONTAINERID:/# psql -h localhost -U POSTGRES_USERNAME DB_NAME
psql (15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

DB_NAME=> SELECT * FROM User;
        user        
--------------------
 POSTGRES_USERNAME
(1 row)

DB_NAME=>
```

I don't see any entries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54781851/2067753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple fix. `DATABASE_URL="postgresql://POSTGRES_USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:5432/DB_NAME?schema=users"` should have been set to `DATABASE_URL="postgresql://POSTGRES_USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:5432/DB_NAME?schema=public"`. Notice I changed `schema=users` to `schema=public`